# Cassandra Acessor annotated interface for insert statement

Tags: java, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-jdbc, nosql

I am developing full fledged application having cassandra 2.1 as back-end and writing API with latest driver. Especially wanted to use Accessor annotated interface for almost all CRUD operations. But, as per the doc only select and update works with JDBI like interface model which is provided by cassandra 2.1.3 driver. Would like to know if INSERT and delete works. Any help much appreaciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found couple of ways to execute insert statements

- Create accessor method that returns "Statement" object, which can be executed using session object
- You can construct a Dao object for the record and invoke mapper.save(daoObj) to save the record.